# How can I put more than one ion-card in a row in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, pdf-generation, typescript2.0

How can I put three ion-card in a row in ionic 2. Please assist if you know. Thanks

Comment: check out [ion-grid](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Grid/)

Comment: @suraj Let me check

Answer (score 1):

For this usecase an ion-grid could be the solution.

More info at : http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/grid/Grid/

Example :

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-md-4>
      <ion-card></ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-md-4>
      <ion-card></ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-md-4>
      <ion-card></ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```